# ASP.NET ASYNC WAIT TASK not processing for multiple request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, webforms

When I am using an async task, after finishing the task process (`**` marked) it gets stuck and doesn't go to the second line (populating the datagridview). If I remove the async task process, it works fine. If I use this async task for a single request XML it works fine, but multiple get stuck.

In this process I am using an Excel file that contains `n` number of data, mapping with a request XML body and post for response.

```cs
protected async void btnProcessFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fubsServiceData = GetFubsServiceData.GetInstance();
    string serviceCategory = ddlAcctServiceCatg.SelectedValue;

    if (!fuFileUpload.HasFile) return;
    if (serviceCategory == "0")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a category.");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            var fileName = GetFileName();
            switch (serviceCategory)
            {
                case "CIF":
                    **gvData.DataSource = await Task.Run(() =>
                        fubsServiceData.GetFubsServiceCifResponseInfo(fileName));**
                    gvData.DataBind();
                    DeleteFile(fileName);
                    btnExportToExcel.Visible = true;
                    break;

                case "CLE":
                    gvData.DataSource = await Task.Run(() =>
                        fubsServiceData.GetFubsServiceClResponseInfo(fileName));
                    gvData.DataBind();
                    DeleteFile(fileName);
                    btnExportToExcel.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvData.Rows)
            {
                string rowType = row.Cells[0].Text;

                row.ForeColor = rowType == "FAILURE" ? Color.DarkRed : Color.Green;
            }
            if (gvData.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Process completed successfully.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what type does `fubsServiceData.GetFubsServiceCifResponseInfo` return , Does it also return a `Task` ?

Comment: It returns a list: public IList<DtoDataGridValue.CifDataGridValueCollection> GetFubsServiceCifResponseInfo(string excelFile)

Comment: With ASP.NET Web Forms you have to register asynchronous code as a Page Task. Check this article out:

[Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)

Comment: Waht is that `MessageBox.Show`? Are you aware that that code is running on the server and the borwser is running on another machine?

Comment: If this is a `webforms` question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: @SajidWasim, still waiting on your answer on this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `webForm` as your solution. It too old and does not support `async` I think (correct me if I am wrong). Unlike client-side [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) and [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), an ASP.NET pipeline is sync only and has a `SynchronizationContext` to ensure that.

Of course, this (SynchronizationContext) is not your issue here, because you use `Task.Run`. It is because an ASP.NET webform has only one thread for processing one client request. After all the work that the ASP.NET pipeline finish process(sync return), it then hooks into the IIS pipeline to finish other things (like the HTTP header, rewrite-outbound-rewrite).

So, here if you are using `async void`, then the pipeline will end immediately, and because IIS is sending all things to the client, it will kill the thread, so after the `await` , the thread does not even exist.

You can use `Task.Run` to make things `parallel`, but it not `async`. And it will use more threadPool threads.

To use `Parallel`, you also should use `yourTask.GetAwater().GetResult()`  to wait for things to finish.

webFom can support async as @paulo-morgado said.

So to use async, you need:

1. `<%@ Page Async="true"  Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  ...  %>`
2. Use `async Task` instead of `async void`, so webForm can know when the method is finished

Comment: and note: wpf/winform  can use `async void`  it because the man thread  / UI thread is runing a  method call loop, and it prevent the thread to finish  see  [`Dispatcher.PushFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.pushframe)

Comment: The can still deadlock depending on `yourTask`. With ASP.NET Web Forms, asynchronous code (tasks or not) must run as page tasks.

Comment: @PauloMorgado  yes,  Web Forms has `SynchronizationContext`  so  an `async` method will deadlock the working thread.  but with `Task.Run` it will not capture `SynchronizationContext`, so it won't deadlock , but will use more threadPool threads, thus it can starve the threadpool when heigh concurrent request happened. I'm not doing much web forms thing, what does the `page tasks` meaning ?

Comment: Using `Task.Run` on a server (ASP.NET) application will hurt performance more than benefit it. It will cause thread switching and if you block on `Task.Run` you'll be wasting a thread that could be used to server another request. Page tasks ([Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)) is the correct way to do asynchronos operations in Web Forms. I had an answer for that but [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) deleted it.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Thanks for your answers. I am following your suggestion. I think I need to study more on async/await.